# Any way to cache Importrange and make it update only once a week?

Tags: google-sheets

I currently use =ImportRange to bring in some data from a public sheet I do not own.

However, it is a lot of data and importrange tries to refresh the data on every page access, and doesn't cache it locally.

Is there a script I can run instead to get the data via importrange, then hard code it into my own sheet and only update it once a week?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Sheets add-on called sheetgo, to automatically update your reference from another sheet. You can use 30 updates for free every month or pay for more updates

But I found this to be effective.

```
function refreshSheet(){

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheet_name);

//Your operations on the sheet

Utilities.sleep(1000);
}

while(true){
Utilities.sleep(604800000);
refreshSheet();}
```